# Running Eclipse IDE Python projects from command line

Tags: python, eclipse

I am quite new to Python and Eclipse. I have my first project, it has about 1500 lines of code and 4 .py files. It runs fine in Eclipse IDE and when I run it from the command line the entry point is `__init__.py`. How do I change the script name to be something meaningful and still retain the eclipse environment.

Thanks in advance
BB

Comment: You can name a file anything you want and just run __init__.py with it.

Comment: python3 init.py

Comment: Ah so a small stub that (with a meaningful name that calls __init__.py. I will give it a go thanks